# unknown hook 'pytest_namespace' in plugin <module 'pytest_assume.plugin'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):

    if browser == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()`
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
    request.config.getoption("--browser")

def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata['project name'] = 'non commerce'
    config._metadata['module name'] = 'customers'
    config._metadata['tester'] = 'Amit'

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_metadata(metadata):
    metadata.pop('JAVA_HOME','none')
    metadata.pop('plugins','none')
```

****When executing the above code following error occurred.****

```
INTERNALERROR> pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_namespace' in plugin <module 'pytest_assume.plugin' from '/home/amita/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_assume/plugin.py'>
```

I have tried by changing the pytest versions also, still same error exists.